# Why does the appearance of the backslash in \url, \path and \texttt look different when using lualatex/pdflatex and the package url/xurl?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, url

Consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\path{C:\} (path)\\
\url{C:\} (url)\\
\texttt{C:\textbackslash} (texttt)
\end{document}
```

Depending on whether I use `pdflatex` or `lualatex` to compile the document, and whether I use the package `url` or `xurl`, I get the following results:

[image]

Why is the backslash sometimes thinner? What I expect is the combination lua-url. But I want to use the `xurl` package for its line breaking feature.

Is this a bug, intended behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: never use the `minimal` class for anything. AFAIK it is only for some internal testing.

Comment: I actually used `standalone` to produce these graphics, let me fix that. Sorry about that

Comment: Just use `article`, simpler. You might also want to check which fonts are used in each case.

Comment: This neatly crops the result like I want it. It doesn't matter here anyway, it all looks the same in all three document classes.

Comment: I just use screen shots, my Linux allows be to just screen shot parts of the screen so super fast.

Comment: @Volker it may make no difference to the font used but it makes a lot of difference to anyone trying to trace tex's execution. `standalone` adds a massive amount of extra computation to crop and isolate the output, and makes tracing tex's behaviour a lot harder. If the question is needs it then it has to be that way, but if it doesn't then it's helpful not to use it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that makes sense, I'll just use `article` next time. Thanks a bunch for your answer!

Comment: @Volker traced it:-) see last update to my answer

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks again

Comment: I reported this to Herbert who says he'll fix it in next release.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\textbackslash` is an encoding dependent command and the default OT1 encoding does not have a backslash so it defaults to `$\backslash$` in that case (which is typically thinner). The cmtt font is designed for verbatim and despite being notionally classed as OT1 encoded in LaTeX it includes most ascii characters in their standard positions. So with url package `\url` and `\path` the cmtt `\` is used so you get the heavier `\`matching the width of the other characters.

You should avoid OT1 encoding anyway and if you add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

then T1 encoding is used and `\textbackslash` will not use the math mode fallback.

`xurl` for reasons I don't immediately see at present as it is a very thin wrapper around `url` makes the math mode fallback get used in the `\url` cases as well. (I may edit this answer later....)

Using luatex and url is similar to using T1 encoding, the encoding in this case is TU (Unicode) and `\textbackslash` simply uses the backslash from the current font so you get the latin modern tt font in all three cases.

and again `xurl` is forcing math mode interpretation of \ as above so even in luatex you are getting the cmsy math mode backslash.

---

the `\` will use math mode using the original `url` package if one setting of `\xurl` is copied:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter

\def\UrlBreaks{%
  \do\/%
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l%
     \do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z%
  \do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L%
     \do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z%
 \do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-%
 \do0\do1\do2\do3\do4\do5\do6\do7\do8\do9\do=\do/\do.\do:%
}
%




%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\path{C:\} (path)\\
\url{C:\} (url)\\
\texttt{C:\textbackslash} (texttt)
\end{document}
```

Oh it is a bug in `xurl` it removes `\\`from all the lists

This gives the tt backslash with `xurl`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}


\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks\do\\}%


%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\path{C:\} (path)\\
\url{C:\} (url)\\
\texttt{C:\textbackslash} (texttt)
\end{document}
```